# Vertical dashed line of a custom height

Tags: punctuation, matrices

I need a vertically dashed line in my matrix, but my current solution looks like the dashes are going out of the `array` environment (and they are - i checked in photoshop). Can I manually shorten it by say 1 mm or 0.5 mm?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{2pt}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc:c}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_n
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that you are typesetting matrices here. Note that `amsmath` provides matrix environments (`matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, etc…), so that you do not need to type your own delimiters around an `array`. (You would want `bmatrix`.)

To get augmented matrices, use the code from the question:
[How does this macro for augmented matrices work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/how-does-this-macro-for-augmented-matrices-work)

---

**Edit:** Included the code for convenience.

```
\usepackage{arydshln}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Put the code in the preamble.

---

You can then use the same syntax as for arrays, but would end up with the code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}[cccc:c]
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_n
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

---

**Edit 2:** Another interesting link:
http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/

Comment: This is also good, but the first solution is kinda easier, no need for renewing stuff (which I was never really good at xD). But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I agree with you. Note however that this is more in line with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/consistent-typography

Answer (score 7):

One possibility, is to tackle the problem in the other sense: instead of shortening the dashed line, you can enlarge the delimiters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\delimitershortfall=0pt
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{2pt}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc:c}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_n
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, there's the (overkill?) solution using `\tikzmark`; this gives you more control for fine tuning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\hfill\tikzmark{a} & b_1 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}\hfill\tikzmark{b} & b_n
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[dashed,dash pattern={on 4pt off 2pt}] ([xshift=0.5\tabcolsep,yshift=7pt]a.north) -- ([xshift=0.5\tabcolsep,yshift=-2pt]b.south);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

This environment is similar of the classical environment `{bmatrix}` of `amsmath` but creates PGF/Tikz under the cells, rows and columns.

It's possible to use that nodes to draw whatever rule you want after the creation of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}
a_{11}  & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 \\
a_{21}  & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1}  & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_n
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw [dashed,shorten > = 2pt, shorten < = 2pt] (1-|5) -- (last-|5) ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]