# bmatrix in beamer not working

Tags: beamer, matrices

I'm unable to use the flags to center the column and add a dashed vertical line in the `bmatrix` environment. This code was working on another LaTeX file but somehow I can't make it work with beamer:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}{c:cc}
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
 -1 & \phantom{+}1 & -1 \\ 
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

By following a suggestion to show a MWE where it DOES work, I found the problem. In the preamble there's a new command that's created, but I don't understand what it's doing.

```
\documentclass[times]{nmeauth}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline

% choose the typewriter font used in algorithms
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{align*}
\newcommand*{\tmp}{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{}} 
\begin{bmatrix}[c:cc]
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
 -1 & \phantom{+}1 & -1 \\ 
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then please show  us an example of a document where this works with `bmatrix `, which does not normally take any arguments as an environment.

Answer (score 1):

`arydshln` doesn't mention `bmatrix` environment, so I've tested your code with `array` and it worked.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{c:cc}
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
 -1 & \phantom{+}1 & -1 \\ 
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it works with array, but I have a lot of equations with bmatrix that I have to copy from an article to a beamer presentation.

Comment: @aaragon   I've found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115997/1952) which combines `arydshln` with `bmatrix` but with some code which changes `matrix` syntax.

Comment: Yes, I found out the problem. Somehow I thought `bmatrix` supported this syntax by default. It's so convenient that I don't understand why it's not available as default. I still don't understand what the macro is doing though.

Comment: @aaragon You can read what is doing in the answer to the [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/how-does-this-macro-for-augmented-matrices-work)