# Compile error with redefined bmatrix and align environment

Tags: environments, align, matrices

I just spent a couple of hours finding the reason for compiling errors in the last example in here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft=true, headsepline=on, twoside
, 11pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}


%matrix environment redef
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother






\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   ~  & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{cc}
     & b 
  \end{array}
\end{align*}  


\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}  


\end{document}
```

The error does not appear if I do not redefine bmatrix environment like discussed here:
[How does this macro for augmented matrices work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/how-does-this-macro-for-augmented-matrices-work)

However, the errors only seam to appear in this special case of using the align environment with a matrix that has empty entries in first column. Do you understand where these errors come from? I have no idea, but this could certainly help later on if similar problems occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanning for the optional argument confuses the alignment parser, due to the empty first cell in the matrix.

You're luckier with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft=true, headsepline=on, twoside
, 11pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

%matrix environment redef
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\env@matrix{O{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the empty first cell problem in any alignment was reported very early on (1995, again in 1997 and '98); it was thought to be fixed in latex 1996/06/01, but actually wasn't, so a fix was applied in `amsmath` 2.0 (1999).  our bugs list says that a "tech note" was issued, but i can't find it; if you could review 'technotes.tex` and make suggestions, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an extra level of bracing to make the lookahead safe.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft=true, headsepline=on, twoside
, 11pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}


%matrix environment redef
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}

\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
{{\ifnum`}=0 \fi\left[\env@matrix}
{\endmatrix\right]\ifnum`{=0 \fi}}
\makeatother






\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   ~  & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{cc}
     & b 
  \end{array}
\end{align*}  


\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     & b 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}  


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's something `amsmath` should do anyway.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, what exactly your solution does? Why< do you need \ifnum'?

Comment: there's been a standing request on our bugs list since 2000; i've added this question as a reference.

Comment: @dbacc It's a standard trick (described  in the texbook) to get a literal unmatched `{` into a macro `\ifnum\`}=0 \fi` expands to nothing but it allows the preceding `{`  to be matched in the definition. (alignments are fussy and normal alternatives like `\bgroup` do not work here.